# How does collisions caculates when developing game in Build an HTML5 Game book

Tags: javascript, math, 2d-games

I don't understand authors login when calculating collisions between two circles (bubbles). Here is the [Calculating collisions](https://books.google.ru/books?id=MPxvCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=px%20%3D%20ex%20%2B%20tdx&source=bl&ots=oZs5Wf7bJF&sig=0fKbOxG2aQGih_efFieKn8b7Ehs&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=W4ybVf-EEIOgsgH986RQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=px%20%3D%20ex%20%2B%20tdx&f=false) section.

Author writes:

> The bubble being fired follows a set of coordinates defined by the
>   equations:
>
> px = ex + tdx py = ey + tdy
>
> where px and py are points on the trajectory of the bubble’s center
>   point. The calculation of px and py happens in jQuery’s animate method
>   and is the standard equation for moving a point along a line. Next,
>   we’ll calculate t at the closest point on this line to the center of
>   the bubble that we’re checking against:
>
> var t = dx * distToBubble.x + dy * distToBubble.y;

I don't understand what `t` is  and why it calculates by the following formula:

`var t = dx * distToBubble.x + dy * distToBubble.y;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little or nothing to do with programming, it is absolutely Math. So I think this question shouldn't be here, but I will answer it just for helping you out.

> I don't understand what is `t`

The line of movement of the bubble being fired is defined by a [parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation), wich parameter is the variable `t`

> why it calculates by the following formula

This is kind of complex, the book just shows the final result of the following calculation. There is a formula to calculate the distance between a point and a line. In this case the point is the center of the target bubble and the line is represented by the parametric equiation previously shown. After you solve that, you can derive that equation to find the minimum distance.

Although there is an easier way to solve this. Using [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between the origin of the target bubble and the coordinates of the shooted bubble with the parametric function and equal it to 0 (perpendicular intersection) you cand find the value for `t`.

The important point here is that the book already solved the problem for you and it is showing the final result so you can use it.

Good luck with your game!

Comment: thanks for the response but I don't yet understand how they are reached to this `var t = dx * distToBubble.x + dy * distToBubble.y;` formula. Could you explain me please?

Comment: I tried to figure it out, but I just know the theory. It looks like some mathemagic to me. Probably they can help you here: http://math.stackexchange.com/ (please post the link to the question here so I can follow up)

Comment: Thanks for the help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353565/how-does-collisions-caculates-when-developing-game-in-build-an-html5-game-book

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the link, I saw that they already answered you. I forgot all what I used to know about geometry I think.